# How to replace MVC 2.0 Html code like "<%: x > y ? a : b %>" to MVC 3.0 cshtml Razor code?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

I have a piece of MVC 2.0 html code is like below, I want replace it with MVC 3.0 Razor code, but I can not make it work using one line code like MVC 2.0.

```
<legend>&nbsp;Please add review for product :<%: Model.Product.ProductName.Length > 25 ? (string)Model.Product.ProductName.Substring(0, 25) + "..." : (string)Model.Product.ProductName %>&nbsp;<i style="color:Red">(&nbsp;<%: (string)Model.Product.Category.CategoryName %>&nbsp;)</i></legend>
```

The only way I can make it work is like below, but it looks not neat. I don't like it, anyone can give me one line code which is worked in MVC 3.0 Razor will be great appreciate!!!

```
<legend>&nbsp;Please add review for product :
    <b>
        @{
            if(Model.Review.Product.ProductName.Length > 25)
            {
                @Model.Review.Product.ProductName.Substring(0, 25); @:...
            }
            else
            {
                @Model.Review.Product.ProductName;
            }
         }
    </b>
    &nbsp;<i style="color:Red">(&nbsp;@Model.Review.Product.Category.CategoryName&nbsp;)</i>&nbsp;</legend>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator (`x > y ? x : y`) is usable in Razor. You just have to wrap it in brackets, so you can clean it up a lot by doing this (I've created a variable for product name for clarity's sake):

```
@{ var productName = Model.Review.Product.ProductName; }
@(productName.Length > 25 ? productName.Substring(0, 25) + "..." : productName)
```

However, since what you're doing is a fairly common task, you might want to think about creating an HTML helper method for the trimming:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public IHtmlString Truncate(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string value, int maxLength)
    {
        if (htmlHelper == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("htmlHelper");

        return value != null && value.Length > maxLength
            ? new HtmlString(htmlHelper.Encode(value.Substring(0, maxLength)) + "&hellip;")
            : new HtmlString(htmlHelper.Encode(value));        
    }
}
```

Then you can just use: `@Html.Truncate(Model.Review.Product.ProductName, 25)` in your view, which is much cleaner.

You could also define an extension method on `string`:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public void Truncate(this string value, int maxLength)
    {       
        return value != null && value.Length > maxLength
            ? value.Substring(0, maxLength) + "..."
            : value;
    }
}
```

which would allow you to just do this: `@Model.Review.Product.ProductName.Truncate(25)`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Which method did you go with?

Comment: Hi Bennor, I create a HtmlHelper extension method. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
<p>
   @(Model.Review.Product.ProductName.Length>25 ? 
            @Html.Raw(Model.Review.Product.ProductName.Substring(0,6)+" ..")
                                  :@Html.Raw(Model.Review.Product.ProductName))
</p>
```

Comment: That should do it. A word to clarify the above, `@()` is inline razor syntax. If you use `@{}` you need to position `@{` and the closing `}` on their own line each.

Comment: Thanks Shyju!!! Your way is also works. I am sorry I can only accept one person's answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Better you can use this Telerik extension to convert ASPX to Razor. It works great for me everytime!.

[ASPX to Razor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d2bfd1ca-9808-417c-b963-eb1ea4896790)